# Invalid column name "account"

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, java-8, netbeans-8

My code is executing well but after it execute on my java output it shows to the error of invalid column name account.

Here is my query String,

```java
{
  String sql = 
  "SELECT [account]" +"[date] 
   FROM [reports].[dbo].[acc] 
   WHERE [account='"+str+"'";
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exceptioncom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name account is not valid
```

Comment: Can you post more of your Code? My guess is, this should be:
{String sql = "SELECT "+account+", "+date+" ...
Also try printing your sql query to check:
System.out.println(sql);

Comment: Your comment should have been an edit of your question, but concerning its content, the error message is pretty straight forward: You are not allowed to name a column `account`. This is likely because it is a reserved keyword in microsoft sql server. Same applies to `date`, by the way. Call them `user_account` and `entry_date` or similar... Maybe use camelCase...

Comment: Also, you have no comma between the 2 fields you have in the select statement. And in your `Where` statement, `[account=` is missing an ending bracket `]`

Comment: thank you , its now working

Comment: Not to mention this looks like it is wide open to sql injection. Munging strings together like this is a recipe for disaster. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
{
  String sql = 
  "SELECT [account]," +"[date] 
   FROM [reports].[dbo].[acc] 
   WHERE [account]='"+str+"'";
}
```